# SELECT N rows before and after the row matching the condition? - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

tbl_A

```
uqAID    A
1        CC
2        AA
3        SS
4        QQ
5        RR
6        UU
7        LL
8        WW
```

tbl_B

```
uqBID    uqAID    B
1        4        NNN
2        4        MMM
3        3        OOO
4        1        PPP
5        6        QQQ
6        4        RRR
7        8        SSS
8        2        TTT
```

With this query

```
SELECT X.B,
        Y.A
FROM tbl_B AS X,
        tbl_A AS Y
WHERE X.uqAID = Y.uqBID
        AND X.A = 'UU'
        AND Y.B = 'QQQ'
```

I am getting the result as `" UU  QQQ"`

but I need to get the result like

```
SS        OOO
CC        PPP
UU        QQQ
QQ        RRR
WW        SSS
```

above and below of two record of UU and QQQ in MS Access

Comment: So ... why aren't you managing that relationship in the model itself?

Answer (score 0):

First, it's going to depend on the order. So you are going to need an order by on your query otherwise there's no way to predict the results you will get.

Assuming it's srder on the Y.B column, you could do something like this to get the QQQ and the two following it:

```
SELECT Top 3 X.B,
        Y.A
FROM tbl_B AS X,
        tbl_A AS Y
WHERE X.uqAID = Y.uqBID
        AND X.A >= 'UU'
        AND Y.B >= 'QQQ'
order by y.a, y.b
```

Then the following to get the two prior to QQQ

```
SELECT Top 2 X.B,
        Y.A
FROM tbl_B AS X,
        tbl_A AS Y
WHERE X.uqAID = Y.uqBID
        AND X.A < 'UU'
        AND Y.B < 'QQQ'
order by y.a desc, y.b desc
```

From there you can union the two result sets together (which is left an exercise for the student). That should get you the two proceeding and following the trigger row.